# Why Does Remesh Never Load On This Model?

Tags: modeling, vertices, remesh, sculpt-mode

When I try to use remesh on this model, it never loads. Blender doesn't crash, but for some reason my CPU and memory just go up to 100%, but the remesh never actually completes and my app just sits there unresponsive until I close it. There are not too many vertices and the topology isn't that crazy. I even tried removing the head of the model but that didn't help. This also happens to other similar models. These models are ones I have done heavy manual edits on in edit mode, since I had not discovered the sculpting tool until a few months ago.

Could it be that there was too much manual vertex editing done to the model so it won't process a new topology?

And what is weird is that in sculpt mode, I have no problem sculpting the model with any of the tools. It is just the remesh tool that does not load.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just found out what the problem was. For some reason, the remesher scaling is skewed for these models and entering values below 1 causes the remesher to try and add millions of vertices to it which would explain why it never loads. When I entered in higher values such as 2, the remesh worked and added tons of vertices on. This is unusual as my newer models need to be tweaked down to .1 or lower to retain their details. These older models were different.